# How to create components with the same properties\methods

Tags: angular, angular-components

Not even sure it is feasible in angular:
I would like to create components which all have few same properties and methods, some kind of inheritance. The components should be based on some kind of a component "template".
I don't want to include in each new components the set of shared properties and methods, I just want to refer them in the HTML or in a component ref instance, wheres they will be defined in the "template"\"parent" - where the components inherit from.
Is it feasible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In angular2+, it is possible to inherit properties and methods from parent component in this way:

`export class yourComponent extends yourBaseComponent`.

You can use all properties and methods of yourBaseComponent in yourComponent through keyword this, as they are properties and method of yourComponent and so it is possibile to use it in HTML template of yourComponent too.